# iOS webapp does not store sessions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

There all,

I was wondering why my webapp doesn't get any session information. In the browser it shows nicely my PHPSESSID, but when i add it to my homescreen it returns nothing with `alert(document.cookie);`. I doesn't have access to the server because it's cross domain.

I use JQuery 1.11.4 with the $.ajax function.

Anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
        url: 'THE_URL?callback=?',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 
            'username': "user",
            'password': "pass"
        },
        success: function(json) { 
            if(json.ok == true)
            {
                console.log(document.cookie);
            }
       }
   });
});
```

The good output (in iOS safari):
[image: Good output]

The wrong output (in iOS homescreen webapp):
[image: Wrong output]

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077518/ios-full-screen-web-app-drops-cookies

Comment: No, this wouldn't solve my problem. I told already that this is cross-domain and i don't have access to there server. To solve this problem, there need to be an fix client-side. Not server-side.